# 429 Error Code from axios api GET request

Tags: node.js, express, react-redux, axios

I'm having an issue with a 429 code error calling for too many requests that I am completely unsure how to solve. I'm getting the error when trying to make an axios api call to my Express server from my React frontend app.
Here is the backend route:

```
app.get('/api/fetchproducts', async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({});
    res.send(products);
  });
```

And here is the axios call from the frontend:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS } from "./types";

export const fetchProducts = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/fetchproducts');

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_PRODUCTS, payload: res.data });
};
```

The error in the console is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 429
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Please let me know if further information is required

Comment: What middleware are you using? Are you accessing the port directly or through some software like nginx?

Comment: Middleware is ReduxThunk and I'm not using any software to access the port although I'm using a cloud9 environment so that may add something I'm really not sure. 

However I have fixed the issue. I had my client side proxy setup to include "/api/*". When I got rid of that and just proxied it directly to the express server URL it worked. Not sure why this is.

Comment: Probably something on your clientside was messing things up? Who knows how computers work, right? :D

Glad it's resolved though.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of an error normally occurs when your API is having rate-limiting enabled.